# Designing a filter using scala - For loop unrolling

Tags: scala, chisel

I am trying to create a synthesizable FIR filter using Chisel. I am reading signed integers from a csv file which I then pass to the FIR filter class as coefficients. Just to give you all a flavor - this is what the coefficient look like:

`-152651856 1233223 ...`

A for loop is used to then do the MAC operation across the coefficients of the filter. I can't find the reason why the for loop is not unrolling properly. It is only synthesizing the last coefficient as a constant.

```
class FIR (val coefficients:Array[Int], val count:Int ) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val X        = Input(Vec(count,SInt(16.W)))
    val Y_out     = Output(SInt(64.W))
  })

  val sum  = Reg(SInt(64.W))
  sum := 0.S(64.W)
  val temp = Reg(Vec(count,SInt(64.W)))


  for(ct <- 0 until count ) {

   temp(ct) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(ct): Int).S
   sum := sum + temp(ct) * io.X(ct)

  }
  io.Y_out := sum

}
```

Here array `coefficients` are the coefficients of the filter passed to the class and `count` is the number of coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to keep in mind is that Chisel is **not** behavioral synthesis. There is no blocking assignment (although it can be emulated). Chisel instead has *last connect semantics* such that the last connection wins. This is primarily useful when the later connections are predicated (ie. guarded by a `when`), but can also be useful for overriding defaults.

To see what's happening, let's pick a value for `count` and unroll the loop:

```scala
// Let count = 4
temp(0) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(0): Int).S                        
sum := sum + temp(0) * io.X(0)
temp(1) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(1): Int).S
sum := sum + temp(1) * io.X(1)
temp(2) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(2): Int).S
sum := sum + temp(2) * io.X(2)
temp(3) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(3): Int).S
sum := sum + temp(3) * io.X(3)
```

Last connect makes this the same as:

```scala
temp(0) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(0): Int).S                        
// sum := sum + temp(0) * io.X(0)
temp(1) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(1): Int).S
// sum := sum + temp(1) * io.X(1)
temp(2) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(2): Int).S
// sum := sum + temp(2) * io.X(2)
temp(3) := new  fromIntToLiteral(coefficients(3): Int).S
sum := sum + temp(3) * io.X(3) // <--- Winning connect to sum
```

What you're presumably trying to do is create the sum incrementally as the for loop executes as one might in Verilog using blocking assignment. We can *emulate* this behavior using a `var` (a variable that we can reassign to) to hold the intermediate values:

```scala
  val sum  = Reg(SInt(64.W))
  val temp = Reg(Vec(count,SInt(64.W)))

  var sumVar = 0.S(64.W)
  for(ct <- 0 until count ) {
   temp(ct) := coefficients(ct).S
   sumVar = sumVar + temp(ct) * io.X(ct)
  }
  sum := sumVar    // Connect the finished logic to the sum's "next" value.
  io.Y_out := sum  // Connect current value of sum register to output
```

I want to highlight a few things here:

1. Note that we use `=` for `sumVar`, think about it like a pointer to a hardware node. We're updating the pointer to point to the new logic we've constructed each iteration
2. I may have misunderstood your intent since my code doesn't look like an FIR I'm familiar with (EDIT: The code is correct, see comments on this answer). Note that in Chisel `Reg` corresponds to an actual, register or array of flip-flops. It is **not** like Verilog `reg`. `Reg` is described here: https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/sequential-circuits.html. You can also take a look at the [Chisel Bootcamp](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp) which uses FIR filters as a motivating example throughout.
3. I noticed you're directly using `fromIntToLiteral`. This is an *implicit class* that isn't really supposed to be user facing. You can just write `coefficients(ct).S`, Scala makes it work without you noticing so long as you do `import chisel3._`. If you want to know more details, implicits are how one can implement [Extension Methods](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-add-new-methods-to-existing-classes) in Scala. When you `import chisel3._` the `.S` method comes from `fromIntToLiteral` implicitly and makes it *look* like `S` is a method defined on `Int`. Think about it as syntactic sugar to make Chisel code more convenient to write.

Comment: Thanks for well written answer @jack-koenig . Just because you mentioned it - I already have my coefficients for the filter as a result I do not need to implement a sliding function mentioned in [Chisel Bootcamp](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp/blob/master/3.4_functional_programming.ipynb) . Thus, that leaves us with the MAC operation which is what you helped me with.

Comment: Oh good, thanks for teaching me something new! `sumVar` is performing a multiply accumulate, so I believe the code in my answer is correct then. I edited my answer to add some info about `fromIntToLiteral` that may interest you.